# Does return finishes a function on Python?

Tags: python, function, return

I'm learning on codeacademy and I was trying to print the following:

```
def trip_cost(p, d, m):
    return rental_car_cost(d) + hotel_cost(d) + plane_ride_cost(p) + m
    print "%s to %s for %s days with an extra %s dollars of spending mone" (trip_cost(p, d, m), p, d, m)
```

The program was telling me nothing was printing on the console, so I proceeded to delete the return line and it worked, so I was wondering if every time a function reaches a `return` it finishes, in that case in the following code I could've save the "and days < 7" ??

```
def rental_car_cost(days):      
    cost = days*40

    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
        return cost    
    elif days >= 3 and days < 7:
        cost -= 20
        return cost
    print cost
```

Comment: Python is indentation-sensitive. You need to indent your code properly.

Comment: thanks I did, It's just I'm bad at copying back. I just edit it

Comment: @NayukiMinase actually, you can have different indentation levels, as long as each block is at the same level. The code worked even if it isn't pritty :)

Comment: This is covered in [the relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#return).

Comment: You are correct, `return` finishes the function.

Answer (score 3):

> so I was wondering if every time a function reaches a return it finishes

Yes, it *returns* to what called it, hence the name.

> in that case in the following code I could've save the `and days < 7`

Yes. Also you could have left it out because `elif` means "else if" so even if you didn't `return` that case would only have been considered if the previous `if` had been false so that it is considered `else`.

Generally we call the code `and days < 7` here *redundant*. It's a good idea to remove redundant code. If redundancy makes something clearer then there's little harm leaving it in, but as a rule redundancy is more likely to confuse someone than to assist them, especially when you get more familiar with the language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can leave out `and days < 7`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `return` finishes the function and nothing else after that line is executed. Your example will work fine for the `if-elif-else` statements, as the appropriate condition will be checked and executed, returning the corresponding `cost`.

As a tip, you can use `elif 3 <= days < 7` instead of `elif days >= 3 and days < 7`. Python is nice like that! In the way your conditions are structured, you can just have `elif days >=3`.

Comment: At that point in the code, `days` is guaranteed to be less than `7`, so there's no need to check for that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yes, added note to simplify `elif` part more.